# Text is blurry in many apps after disconnecting external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, text

I have a 2015 Retina MacBook pro. Sometimes I connect it to a 24" Dell external monitor via thunderbolt->dvi. Whenever I disconnect the  monitor, many apps (chrome, most noticeably) have blurry text. This can be corrected by opening "displays" and scaling the text up and then back down, but this is quite annoying.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: could you look in the Console what the widowserver is deciding to do as for the setting after you disconnect.

Comment: Pasted at this gist: https://gist.github.com/Soares/a183d3bad69b533892b7